# Method for Changing django template to PDF that having either bootstrap or css or both

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have tried via weasyprint , pdfkit but showing errors even though if all errors removed, its showing very unsimilar output as expected .. Can anyone tell me what to do in changing django template that contains either Bootstrap or Css Or both in Django
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the url where you can find how To Generate PDF in Django with WeasyPrint.

https://www.bedjango.com/blog/how-generate-pdf-django-weasyprint/

Weasyprint doesn't work well with bootstrap because it has media query and it is ignored by weasyprint.

This is the reference [Link to Github site](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/270) for clarity.

You can see the "Ignored ..." messsages in WeasyPrint error log(if you ever initilised).

So its better to use CSS for the print-pages and Internal CSS.